# disabling individual items in knockout-sortable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

In knockout-sortable, I know that you can disable a sortable list using `isEnabled` in the `sortable` binding.  I also know you can disable moving items using `cancelDrop` in a `beforeMove` function.  The problem is, `isEnabled` disables the whole list, and `cancelDrop` can only be called after the item is already dragged and dropped onto another `sortable`.

Is there a way to disable `sortable`'s click/drag behavior on certain contained items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the jQuery UI sortable options `items` or `cancel` for this purpose. Docs here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items.

You would add them in a binding like:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="sortable: { data: tasks, options: { cancel: '.prevent' } }">
```

or globally like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.options.cancel = ".prevent";
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2wEX3/

Comment: Oh man, that's a slightly embarrassing.  I didn't dig into the jQuery UI options too deeply; I knew I missed something relatively obvious.  This works tremendously!  Thanks RP!