# Disabling drag and drop in knockout js sortable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a way to disable the drag and drop when using sortable in knockout js. I have a square grid with 5*5 squares inside it. I want to disable drag and drop for some squares not all.. How can this be done? any suggestion..

Comment: possible duplicate of [disabling individual items in knockout-sortable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611775/disabling-individual-items-in-knockout-sortable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is support for this in the jQuery UI sortable  [this on the demo page.](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items)

You just need to add a special class to your non sortable items (e.g with the `css` binding) then you need use the [cancel option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel) where you can set this non sortable class name.

And you can specify options for the `sortable` binding with the `options` parameter:

```
data-bind="sortable: {data: items, options: { cancel: '.no-sort' }}"
```

A simple demo HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="sortable: {data: items, options: { cancel: '.no-sort'}}">
    <li data-bind="text: name, css: { 'no-sort': disabled}"></li>
</ul>
```

And the JS:

```
var vm = {
    items: [
        {name: 'name1', disabled: false},
        {name: 'name2', disabled: false},
        {name: 'name3', disabled: true},
        {name: 'name4', disabled: false},
        {name: 'name5', disabled: true}
    ]
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LpKyx/)

Comment: Thanks for solution but if you move a item above "no sort" item it will move down what if i want to keep a item on top and never move?

Comment: @ImranRashid then you need the set the `items` options. See the [jquery demo page](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items) and also this http://jsfiddle.net/5s86r/

Comment: Can you please look at my code suddenly it stop working i cant find out whats wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437988/knockout-sortable-not-working-correctly