# knockout-sortable disable item as drop target

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable, knockout-sortable

My question is very similar to this one: [disabling individual items in knockout-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611775/disabling-individual-items-in-knockout-sortable)

But the accepted answer keeps the item as a drop target.  (The item itself isn't draggable, but you can drop items on top of it).  I'm wondering if there's a good way to disable the item completely.  jQuery recommends never enabling it in the first place like so: ( http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items )

```
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
    });
```

But I'm not sure how to use that logic with the "sortable" binding.

Since this only really applies to items at the beginning or end of the list, I could potentially add them separately from the "sortable" bind.  But if there's a somewhat elegant way to do it otherwise, I'd be better off with that.  I have the feeling I'm missing an obvious way built in to the knockout-sortable plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking from the answer you mentioned, is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
<div class="container" data-bind="sortable: { data: tasks, options: { items: 'li:not(.ui-state-disabled)' } }">
```

Globally:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.options.cancel = "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)";
```

Comment: Yes!! I had to change it a little bit since I didn't post my actual code earlier.  I simplified it down to this, where isDraggable is a property of my KO item:

`<div class="container" data-bind="sortable: { data: myItems, options: { items: '.draggableItem' } }">
                <div data-bind="text: text, css: { draggableItem: isDraggable }">
                </div>
            </div>`